# Select the value in the select options

Tags: php, arrays, forms, session

I'm working on my PHP to set up the html tags for the select options. I have stored the strings in the array and I want to check with the variable `$_SESSION["day_cycle"]` to see if the string is empty. If the variable show as a empty string, I want to select the value `Immediately`, but it will always select the value `Delayed` in the select options.

I have also tried:

```
if(!$v == $_SESSION["day_cycle"])
{
    $selected = "Immediately";
}
```

And this:

```
if($_SESSION["day_cycle"] == '')
{
    $selected = "Immediately";
}
```

It will always select the value `Delayed` in the select options.

Here is the full code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="label-control" value="">Send message:</label>

    <?php
        $html = '<form method="post" action="">
        <select name="sendmessage" id="sendmessage" style="width: 300px;" value="">';
        $values = array('unknown', 'Immedatiely', 'Delayed');

        foreach($values as $v)
        {
            $selected = '';

            if($v == 'unknown')
            {
                $title = '';
            }
            else
            {
                $title = $v;
            }

            if(!$v == $_SESSION["day_cycle"])
            {
               $selected = "selected";
            }
            $html .= "<option $selected value='$v'>$title</option>";
        }
        $html .= "</form>
        </select>";
        echo $html;
    ?>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is I want to check with the variable `$_SESSION["day_cycle"]` to check that if the variable return as a empty string, then I want to select the value `Immediately` in the select options and if the variable have a return string I want to select the value `Delayed`.

Can you please show me an example how I can use to check the variable to see if the variable return the string or not so I can select the value I want?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to check if a variable is empty, simply do  `if (empty($_SESSION["day_cycle"]))`

Comment: `Immediately` != `Immedatiely`, or was that a typo?

Comment: @Qirel Thank you, I have tried it but it will select the value `Delayed`. Any idea?

Comment: again; was that a typo? I asked this earlier but no response.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am sorry but i dont understand what you mean by a typo? what is a typo?

Comment: you mean `Immediately` and `Delayed` should be in a `select option` such that when you session is null then `Immediately` is selected automatically and when session is true `Delayed` is selected also automatically? wright?

Comment: A typo is short form for "typographical" (error), meaning that you misspelled "Immedatiely", which would not have worked in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be unrelated, but you misspelled `Immediately` when populating your array.  You also closed your `form` and `select` tags in the wrong order.  I eliminated the `$html` variable, but otherwise the following solution isn't much different and running it in a test environment worked:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="label-control" value="">Send message:</label>
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="sendmessage" id="sendmessage" style="width: 300px;" value="">
    <?php
        $day_cycle = $_SESSION["day_cycle"];
        if ($day_cycle == '1')
            $day_cycle='Immediately';

        $values = array('unknown', 'Immediately', 'Delayed');

        foreach($values as $v)
        {
            $selected = '';

            if($v == 'unknown')
                $title = '';
            else
                $title = $v;

            if($v == $day_cycle)
               $selected = " selected";

            echo "<option$selected value='$v'>$title</option>";
        }
    ?>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, but when the variable `$_SESSION["day_cycle"]` don't have the value 1,2,3,4 or whatever it is, how I can select the value `Immediately`?

Comment: That's what the `if (empty($day_cycle)) $day_cycle='Immediately';` part does

Comment: I am sorry for the confused but what you can see that I am using `day_cycle` in `$_SESSION["day_cycle"]`, it show that the day start from 0 to 30 days or whatever it is so if I have the value `1`, how I can select the value of `Immediately` in the select options?

Comment: Then it would need to be `if ($day_cycle == '1') $day_cycle='Immediately';` I'll update the answer accordingly.